# Why am I getting AttributeError while trying to execute "import requests" from my Mac terminal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to web-scrape using `requests` and Python 3.10 from my Mac. But I receive this error just from trying to import `requests`:

```
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/utils.py", line 30, in <module>
    from .cookies import RequestsCookieJar, cookiejar_from_dict
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/cookies.py", line 159, in <module>
    class RequestsCookieJar(cookielib.CookieJar, collections.MutableMapping):
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'
```

Do I need to downgrade my python version, or what could I do?

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk, as shown in the post, the code is literally `import requests` - the error is coming from the library code

Comment: please open up your Python interpreter again as you did above and post the output of `print(sys,version)`.

Comment: `requests` is not currently marked as being 3.10-compatible by the pyreadiness website. That doesn't mean that it *definitely* isn't compatible... But you may just have to use Python 3.9 for a while. https://pyreadiness.org/3.10/

Answer (score 2):

The abstract base classes (abc's) in the `collections` module were moved to `collections.abc` in Python 3.3; in Python 3.10, the aliases were [removed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html).

Your post doesn't make it clear what version of `requests` you're using or whether you require a new Python 3.10 feature, but hopefully one of the following options will work for you:

- Create a Python 3.9 virtual environment and use the same version of `requests`, so those aliases are available.
- See if `requests` has a newer version available that is compatible with Python 3.10. (Note many third-party libraries are not yet compatible.)